# Prioritize filter single property in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I have node post with property like: _id,type(int)

And now i want to filter by property type like that:

First,I want match every type in 1,2,3

Second, If it's doesn't match any collection then I want to return any collection of another type like 4,5,6 in my database.

How can i do it? Thank you

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far and maybe show a more detailed example as it's hard to decode what do you really want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of nodes for the first filter, and choose which filter to use:

```
WITH [1, 2, 3] AS firstFilter,
     [4, 5, 6] AS secondFilter
OPTIONAL MATCH (N) WHERE N.type IN firstFilter
WITH CASE WHEN count(N) > 0 
          THEN firstFilter 
          ELSE secondFilter 
     END AS filter    
MATCH (N) WHERE N.type IN filter
RETURN N
```